# Can I carry spices on a US domestic flight?

Tags: airport-security, hand-luggage, prohibited-items

I will be traveling to Portland from Florida next week. I want to take a jar or two of mixed, powdered spices such as cinnamon, nutmeg, cloves. I will be traveling with only a carry on, and would put them in that bag. Can I do this it?

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any reason you cannot carry the items you mention.Dried fruit is allowed as are salsa and sauces which are somewhat close to spices.

From the Transportation Security Administration (TSA) website:

[What Can I Bring?](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring)

> Planning ahead and packing properly can facilitate the screening
>   process and ease your travel experience at the airport.
>
> **For items not listed here, simply snap a picture or send a question to AskTSA on Facebook Messenger or Twitter**. We look forward to
>   answering your questions, from 8 a.m. to 10 p.m. ET weekdays and 9
>   a.m. to 7 p.m. weekends/holidays.

Answer (score 4):

There's a TSA app which covers practically everything and it's called [Can I bring](https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_home.aspx). You just enter whatever you want and it shows whether you can carry it on and whether it's ok to check it in.

In this case, https://apps.tsa.dhs.gov/mytsa/cib_results.aspx?search=spices is the URL you wanted. 
[image]

Comment: Better link that works on desktop: https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/whatcanibring/items/spices-dry